# java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but HederListView did not receive a notification

Tags: java, android, listview

I am using [HeaderListView](https://github.com/applidium/HeaderListView) in my project. It works fine. But in at one place when i try to use notifydatesetchanges then it throws the IllegalStateException. This happens only when i tried to scroll fast through my list view.

here's the stack trace

```
 05-12 12:03:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(22291): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes. [in ListView(-1, class HeaderListView$InternalListView) with Adapter(class android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter)]
 05-12 12:03:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(22291):   at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1555)
 05-12 12:03:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(22291):   at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchMove(AbsListView.java:3549)
 05-12 12:03:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(22291):   at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3424)
 05-12 12:03:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(22291):   at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7736)
 05-12 12:03:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(22291):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2210)
 05-12 12:03:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(22291):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1945)
 05-12 12:03:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(22291):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
 05-12 12:03:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(22291):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
 05-12 12:03:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(22291):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
 05-12 12:03:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(22291):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
 05-12 12:03:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(22291):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
 05-12 12:03:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(22291):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
 05-12 12:03:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(22291):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
 05-12 12:03:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(22291):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
 05-12 12:03:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(22291):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
 05-12 12:03:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(22291):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
 05-12 12:03:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(22291):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
 05-12 12:03:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(22291):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
 05-12 12:03:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(22291):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
 05-12 12:03:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(22291):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
 05-12 12:03:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(22291):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
 05-12 12:03:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(22291):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
 05-12 12:03:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(22291):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2068)
 05-12 12:03:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(22291):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1515)
 05-12 12:03:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(22291):   at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2466)
 05-12 12:03:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(22291):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2016)
 05-12 12:03:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(22291):   at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7916)
 05-12 12:03:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(22291):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4031)
 05-12 12:03:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(22291):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3910)
 05-12 12:03:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(22291):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3460)
 05-12 12:03:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(22291):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3510)
 05-12 12:03:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(22291):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3479)
 05-12 12:03:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(22291):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3586)
 05-12 12:03:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(22291):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3487)
 05-12 12:03:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(22291):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3643)
 05-12 12:03:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(22291):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3460)
 05-12 12:03:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(22291):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3510)
 05-12 12:03:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(22291):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3479)
 05-12 12:03:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(22291):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3487)
 05-12 12:03:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(22291):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3460)
 05-12 12:03:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(22291):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5728)
 05-12 12:03:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(22291):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5659)
 05-12 12:03:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(22291):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5630)
 05-12 12:03:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(22291):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5808)
 05-12 12:03:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(22291):   at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
 05-12 12:03:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(22291):   at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
 05-12 12:03:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(22291):   at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiv
```

I have tried many solution and go through lot of search but didn't find any solid solution.

here's my code.

```
HeaderListView listView;
MyAdapter myAdapter;
ArrayList<String> eventList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

code to get list first time.

```
private class GetList extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    ArrayList<String> loadMoreList;
    @Override
    public String doInBackground(String... params) {
        loadMoreList = WebFunctions.getEventList(params[0] ,params[1], params[2], params[3]);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreExecute() {

        }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String string) {
        if(loadMoreList != null){
            if(loadMoreList.size() > 0){

                eventList.clear();
                eventList.addAll(loadMoreList);
                myAdapter = new MyAdapter(thisContext, eventList);
            } 
      }
}
```

Code to get more items of list.

```
 private class LoadMoreList extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    ArrayList<String> loadMoreList;
    @Override
    public String doInBackground(String... params) {
        loadMoreList = WebFunctions.getEventList(params[0] ,params[1], params[2], params[3]);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreExecute() {

        }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String string) {
        if(loadMoreList != null){
            if(loadMoreList.size() > 0){
                eventList.addAll(loadMoreList);
                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: You must called `myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` from Main UI Thread.

Comment: onPostExecute considered to be UI Thread.

Comment: from where you are calling LoadMoreList() this class

Comment: post log cat text rather Image

Comment: called myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(), still crashing with same error.

Comment: LoadMoreList() called when list reached to last row

Comment: I mentioned earlier, this happens only when i tried to scroll fast through my list view.

Answer (score 1):

Actually problem was in the HeaderListView library but now the error has been fixed.
You can see in this [link](https://github.com/applidium/HeaderListView/pull/11) that the issue has been solved.